# Calculating the difference of two values within a group and given period (R)

Tags: r, difference

may the answer is somewhere elese, but I don't find it.
My problem is, that I want to calculate the difference of a value within a group but only in a given Timespan.(With other words: I want to calculate the value difference of a country within e.g. 5 days)

```
Country <- c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada")
Date = c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-01",  "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04")
Value <- c(5,6,7,9,1,3,4,5,0,5,10,15)
df <- data.frame(Country, Date, Value)
```

So again, I would like add a new column where the differnce of the Value for all countries between a given timespan is. My Dataframe should at the end look like the following example, where are the differences of the Value within each group between the "04-01-2021" and the "02-01-2021" is given.

So at the at the dataframe should somehow look like the following:

```
df$ValueDif <- c(3,3,3,3, 2,2,2,2,10,10,10,10)
```

`view(df)`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your dates in `df` only span 4 days. How does this work if you have 6 days, e.g., how are days assigned to a specific timespan?

Comment: Do you need the difference between the latest and the oldest date for each country?

Comment: Im not sure if I got your question right. Acutally those was just examples my orignally data have daily data for 2.5 years, 2019 to 2022 but I only want the dates/ difference in value of 2020. That mean, how much did the value rise in one year.

Comment: @Vishal A. so I dont need the differences of dates, I need differences in the Values. And not for latest and oldest, istead I need it to specific dates. but for each Country, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(diffValue = Value[Date == as.Date("2021-01-04")] - Value[Date == as.Date("2021-01-02")])
```

It will give you output like this:

```
df1
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Country [3]
   Country Date       Value diffValue
   <chr>   <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Germany 2021-01-01     5         3
 2 Germany 2021-01-02     6         3
 3 Germany 2021-01-03     7         3
 4 Germany 2021-01-04     9         3
 5 USA     2021-01-01     1         2
 6 USA     2021-01-02     3         2
 7 USA     2021-01-03     4         2
 8 USA     2021-01-04     5         2
 9 Canada  2021-01-01     0        10
10 Canada  2021-01-02     5        10
11 Canada  2021-01-03    10        10
12 Canada  2021-01-04    15        10
```

P.S: I've hardcoded the dates in the code, to comply with your question.

**EDIT**
In order to get the nearest date corresponding to what you are looking for, you can use the `birk` library. There's a function called `which.closest`. It will give you the nearest value.

The code looks like below:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(diffValue = Value[Date == as.Date("2021-01-04")] - 
           Value[Date == as.Date(Date[which.closest(df$Date, as.Date("2020-12-31"))])])
```

And output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Country [3]
   Country Date       Value diffValue
   <chr>   <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Germany 2021-01-01     5         4
 2 Germany 2021-01-02     6         4
 3 Germany 2021-01-03     7         4
 4 Germany 2021-01-04     9         4
 5 USA     2021-01-01     1         4
 6 USA     2021-01-02     3         4
 7 USA     2021-01-03     4         4
 8 USA     2021-01-04     5         4
 9 Canada  2021-01-01     0        15
10 Canada  2021-01-02     5        15
11 Canada  2021-01-03    10        15
12 Canada  2021-01-04    15        15
```

In the above example, I have checked the nearest date in the second part and not the first. You can use the same syntax there as well.

Comment: this will not work for dates outside the range 2021-01-01 - 2021-01-04 ?

Comment: I have hardcoded the dates as these dates were mentioned in the question. To make it dynamic, we can pass a variable, instead of passing a hardcoded value.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats pretty much I needed! One additional Question: If there is no Value at the specific date it should take the next near one, so if there is no value for 2021-01-01 it shall take 2021-01-02 etc.....

Comment: I've edited the answer according to your needs.